# Text-align does not apply to images

Tags: html, css

I just wrote the following code

```html
<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/150" id="test">
```

```css
#test {
    text-align: center;
}
```

But the image is not centering. I also used `text-align: right` which did not work either. I can use float and margin-left but I'm curious why its not working with text-align.

Answer (score 17):

Have a look at [text-align css property as described on w3.org website](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#alignment-prop). It says that this property *applies to block containers*.

Now, the `<img>` tag itself is not a container (it cannot contain any thing) hence the text-align property does not work as expected. To make an image center-align, there are various ways; the simplest of them is to specify `text-align: center` on its parent element.

Answer (score 5):

> This property specifies how the inline content of a block is aligned,
>   when the sum of the widths of the inline boxes is less than the width
>   of the line box.

Try putting the img in a div with inline-block specified and the first image as the background image of the div.

something like:

```
<div style="display: block; text-align: center; background-image:url([your_first_image]);">
    <img src="[your_second_image]"/>
</div>
```

However, this probably will not work on an image, you need to use float, padding or something of that nature.

Comment: @icktoofay sorry, I was doing it on the fly. Thanks for the correction. I have been writing too much c today! :)

Comment: Why do you want the `div` to have `display: inline-block`?

Comment: @Arjan That was how I parsed the specification on the text-align attribute to work. It is applied to the "inline content of a block". It will also work on plain "block".

Comment: If you make a div display as an inline-block then it will shrink-wrap the content, so centring it won't make a lot of difference.

Answer (score 4):

```
img {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

It should work! It worked for me :D

Answer (score 2):

`text-align` is used for aligning the text *within* an element. An `img` element has no text inside of it to center, so it does nothing. `float`, which floats the element within its parent, is probably what you want here.

Comment: thanks but this website is saying you can use `text-align:center` http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol7/html_no10.htm

Comment: @Hira: I don't see where it says that. It says you can apply it to the parent element, and indeed, that will work, but it does not say that you can apply `text-align: center;` to an `img` tag and have it work. (It does show a few examples like that, but then explains that they will not work.)

Comment: `<style type="text/css">
  .centeredImage
    {
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    }
</style>` i think so this code in blog shows do what i am doing

Comment: @Hira: It goes on to say: "That is (or seems to be) the easiest and most elegant solution. And it is - for Explorer browsers. Other browsers [...] don't allow you to convert images from inline to block."

Comment: @Hira: (although I'd say their explanation is wrong; you can turn `img` elements into block-level elements, but `text-align` should do nothing to it, rather than center it as in Internet Explorer)

Comment: There isn't a `float: center`…

Comment: @Quentin: True. If you want to center an `img` and you're okay with text not flowing around the sides, you can use `margin: 0 auto;`.

Comment: @Quentin: Sorry, `display: block;`, too.

Answer (score 1):

I try this and it works fine :

- **In the CSS:**

  ```
  .centreimage {  
      text-align: center; 
  }
  ```
- **In the HTML:**

  ```
  <p class="centreimage">
     <img src="Images/blababla.png">
  </p>
  ```

Comment: You should close your image-tag

Answer (score 1):

Not the best practice text-align to align images.

> "The tricky thing about the text-align property is that you can only align text with it - you can't use it to move block-level elements like images. Some browsers will align images or tables with this property, but it's not reliable, as you've found." --[Jennifer Kyrnin, About.com](http://webdesign.about.com/od/graphics/f/blfaqtxtalgimg.htm)

- You can use the deprecated `img` attribute align="center", Although you won't use. This way tags and style are mixed, and, to worsen, there are vertical and horizontal spaces around the full image.

  ```
  <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/150" align="center"> <-- Wrong way
  ```
- The best way to solve this is using CSS. Setting the image as div's background then the div's space will be your image's space and you can use margins to put it in place. You can try to use one of [these others techniques](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/)

CSS background-image Technique:

```
background:url('path_to_img') center center no-repeat; /* div center */
background:url('path_to_img') center 0      no-repeat; /* div horizontal center */
background:url('path_to_img') 0      center no-repeat; /* div vertical center */
```

Comment: I have used `text-align: center;` on images before, you just need to set the display to block or put the image inside a div and it works fine.

Comment: Also, images are not block elements, they are inline-block elements.

Answer (score 0):

Another way -- you can wrap it around a table. see below.
We had to do it this way in a stylesheet.

```
<html>
<table border="0" width="530" >
<td align="center" valign="center">
<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/150" id="test">
</img>
</td>
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider learning about the CSS `display` property, a very important CSS property in my opinion, at least when dealing with positioning and alignment. The property is set to different values on different elements by default. **Assuming the `position` property is set to the `static` value**, `block` and `inline` take up **the entire parent element's width**. `block` will be on its own line while `inline` shares the line with other elements. 
Elements like `p` tags and `h1`s are block level elements. Elements like `span` tags and `em`s are inline elements. *Images* however are neither!

Images have a default display value of `inline-block`. This means it has the characteristics of inline and block elements - You can set the width and height (like block level elements), it is on the same line as other elements (like inline level elements), and **the container is the width and padding - nothing else.**

The CSS rule `text-align: center;` centers the element in its *container*. This means for  p elements it will be fine because the display is set to block. For images, however, you cannot center it (so nothing will happen) unless you put it in a div (parent element container) because, assuming the **width is set to 100%**, there is nothing to center it in, nothing to be aligned with. Consider the following example:

```css
body * {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p> This is a <span> !!Span element containing!! paragraph !!Span element containing!!</span>about lorem ipsum, the infamous place holder text. Lorem ipsum is supposedly Latin, but not really. That's all. </p>
  <img width = '200' src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZTPs.png">
  <p> The display of p is block, span inline, img inline-block. That's why the image's border doesn't stretch and the others do (you may not notice it but they do)</p>
</body>
```

A good workaround is setting the display to block. This will make ti stretch so there is something to center it in. As soon as there is *something* that acts as a parent container, ether it be changing the display (the border is what you are aligning it on) or enclosing it in a div (the div is what you are aligning it on) the aligning will then work.

Answer (score 0):

because it is "text"-align.

the property is designed to work a certain way and given a certain name.

Interestingly, if a the property is applied to a container that has image+text then the alignment works for text as well as image.

```css
.one{
text-align: center}
```

```html
<div class="one">
<p>hello pal</p>
<img src="https://cn.i.cdn.ti-platform.com/content/22/showpage/regular-show/za/regularshow-200x200.png">
</div>
```